# I want to get user and password Facebook

Tags: ios

I make an App login with Facebook account. I did it and I had userName, userID, tokenkey from Facebook. how to take username and password (which use to login facebook)??

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch these details because of security concerns.
You can use the [graph API Explorer](https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer) for the available details and request structure.